# How to set the locale code in sending email

Tags: magento, setlocale

I created an email template of abandoned applications, when I send an email  check the store's order to send properly, but now lack the language set to go all correctly.

Example:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($order->getStoreId());
$emailTemplate->send(...)
```

Already tried to use, but does not translate

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->setLocaleCode('pt_BR');
```

or

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->init('pt_BR', true)
```

This sending it's correct for each store however the language is not changing, wanted to know how to set the corrent language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This causes change the email template to be sent

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale('pt_BR')->init('frontend', true);
```